# Filter parent object based on child object containing value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object, `benefitGroups` that contains `benefits`. Each item in `benefits` contain an array of `coverageLineIds`. How can I filter the `benefitGroups` object to only contain benefits that include ID 1 in the `coverageLineIds` array?

```
const benefitGroups=  [
     {
      id: 1,
      name: "Benefit Group A",
      benefits: {
         id: 1,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit Z",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit X",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      },
      {
         id: 3,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit Y",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      },
    },
     {
      id: 2,
      name: "Benefit Group B",
      benefits: {
         id: 4,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit I",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      },
      {
         id: 5,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit J",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      },
      {
         id: 6,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit H",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      },
    },
     {
      id: 3
      name: "Benefit Group C",
      benefits: {
         id: 7,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit D",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      },
      {
         id: 8,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit E",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      },
      {
         id: 9,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit F",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      },
    },
]
```

In the above example, I would want to return Benefit Group A and B as their benefits contain coverage line IDs of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is invalid. Your benefits should be in array.

Once, fixed here is what you're looking for:

```
const id = 1;

const result = benefitGroups.filter((group) => {
  return group.benefits.some((benefit) => benefit.coverageLineIds.includes(id));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const benefitGroups=  [
     {
      id: 1,
      name: "Benefit Group A",
      benefits: [{
         id: 1,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit Z",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit X",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      },
      {
         id: 3,
         benefitGroupId: 1,
         name: "Benefit Y",
         coverageLineIds: [1, 2]
      }],
    },
     {
      id: 2,
      name: "Benefit Group B",
      benefits: [{
         id: 4,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit I",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      },
      {
         id: 5,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit J",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      },
      {
         id: 6,
         benefitGroupId: 2,
         name: "Benefit H",
         coverageLineIds: [1]
      }],
    },
     {
      id: 3,
      name: "Benefit Group C",
      benefits: [{
         id: 7,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit D",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      },
      {
         id: 8,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit E",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      },
      {
         id: 9,
         benefitGroupId: 3,
         name: "Benefit F",
         coverageLineIds: [3, 4]
      }],
    },
]

var filteredBenefitGroups = benefitGroups.filter((group) => {
    let benefits = group.benefits.filter(benefit => benefit.coverageLineIds.indexOf(1) !== -1);
    return benefits.length ? true : false;
});
console.log(filteredBenefitGroups);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).